# google analytics invalid credentials for a specific account

Tags: php, google-analytics, oauth-2.0, google-analytics-api

Hi i am using a different account for google analytics and is returning an error:

```
GDataauthErrorAuthorizationInvalid Credentials
```

Though for my previous account is working fine. it could be because i missed some things in the registration process, could anyone give me a detailed steps for the registration to work for oauth 2.0 using api_key for google analytics v2.4

thank you

```
//returns session token for multiple calls to API
function get_session_token($onetimetoken) {
    $output = call_api($onetimetoken, "https://www.google.com/accounts/AuthSubSessionToken");

    if(preg_match("/Token=(.*)/", $output, $matches)) {
        $sessionToken = $matches[1];
    } else {
        echo "Error authenticating with Google.";
        exit;
    }

    return $sessionToken;
}

//gets the data
function call_api($sessionToken,$url){
    $curl = curl_init($url);

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
    if ($_SESSION['authSub']==true){
        $curlheader[0] = sprintf("Authorization: AuthSub token=\"%s\"/n", $sessionToken);
    } else {
        $curlheader[0] = "Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=" . $sessionToken;
    }
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $curlheader);

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    return $response;       
}

$requrlvisits = sprintf("https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v2.4/data?ids=ga:%s&dimensions=ga:date&metrics=ga:visits,ga:pageviews,ga:bounces,ga:timeOnSite&start-date=%s&end-date=%s&sort=ga:date&key=%s",$get_profid[9],$date1,$date2,$api_key);
                            // echo $requrlvisits;

                            $visitsxml = call_api($_SESSION['sessionToken'],$requrlvisits);             
                            $visits = parse_data($visitsxml);

                            print_r($visitsxml);
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm scratching my head with a similar issue.

Comment: @Lenwood you have to update to their latest api and also use Oauth 2.0  in authenticating the users. they are now using API_KEY.